# can you translate a text from english language to another language using Php?

Tags: php

i'm developing a website where most of it's customers are not English speaking, but i'm writing down it's details like, about us, how it works e.t.c, in English. So is it possible to translate an entire page from English to another desired language using Php, and how? Thank ya.

Comment: This is far too broad a question.

Comment: use google translator  you can also do it by your self but that is broad topic

Comment: sorry about that, but i'm trying to to enable a function or so, that would translate my page to another particular language

Comment: if you want the translations to be professional, you should mark phrases individually, take into account the pluralization forms, enable UTF-8 support, and enable localization of measurement units

Comment: To add on what Dan said, do not use machine translations for anything professional unless you "must". If a site gives me Google Translated Swedish text instead of professional English, I'm out of there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any function from the PHP core that can do the "translate" thingy, but you can use API to achieve what you want to do. Here is the link to the Google translate API: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Tutorial of using the Google translate API: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/